# Is it possible to connect both the remote and my android app to my HDR-AZ1, at the same time?

Tags: camera, sony

I have a Sony HDR-AZ1 with the RM-LVR2V remote.

I'm currently integrating the Remote API into an Android app that we are developing. The app will download video and photos from the camera, and transfer them to our web service.

What I've discovered is that it appear as if only one device can be connected to the camera at any single time - either my smartphone or my RM-LVR2V remote. Not both at once, which I would need. I'm not sure if this is the case, but it appear as if I have my smartphone connected to the camera, then I cannot connect my remote, and vice versa. Is this correct?

Is there some way to connect both my RM-LVR2V and my smartphone to the camera, at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately connecting both at once is not possible.  The Camera only supports one WiFi connection at a time.  You may want to look into using something like a SmartWatch 2 or 3 to connect to the phone and then the phone to the camera to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid that was the case. Do you have any insight into why that is? To me it sounds like a limitation imposed by the firmware, rather than the WiFi-adapter, and I can't see the reason for adding such a limitation? Anyway, I will probably end up using something like a SmartWatch. The only limitation I see with that, compared to the RM-LVR2V, would be that you loose the live preview. I haven't looked in to the SmartWatch option yet, but I guess it would be difficult to pass a live stream over the Bluetooth transport from the phone to the watch, right?

Comment: I believe the limitation is HW related in that a direct WiFi connection only supports a 1:1 mapping.  Live preview is actually not difficult to implement on a SmartWatch using the Camera Remote API.  The liveview stream is easily captured and can be sent as a series of images to a watch.  There are various apps on Google Play that implement this functionality that you could take a look at as examples.